# Wait between sending login and commands to serial port using Plink

Tags: batch-file, serial-port, plink

I want to make connection by serial port in `PLINK`. The problem is that the code (below) doesn't work because  file `remove.txt` is all sent at once, while terminal is asking for a login and before it starting asking for commands. There is any possibilities to login first and then execute command file? The `test` is saved serial session (com5 baud 115200)

Command:

```
C:\PROGRA~1\PuTTY\plink -load test < C:\Users\qj2p70\Desktop\remove.txt
```

`remove.txt` file:

```
root
root
cd /cfg_usr/delphi/etc
rm vip_coding_yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the problem is that the device on the serial port discards an input that comes too early.

You can solve that by pausing between individual inputs/lines. But then you cannot use an input file. You need generate the input using a "program" that can do the pauses and pipe that input to `plink`. An easy way to implement such program is using a compound statement in a batch file:

```
(
  echo root
  timeout /t 5 > nul
  echo root
  timeout /t 5 > nul
  echo cd /cfg_usr/delphi/etc
  timeout /t 5 > nul
  echo rm vip_coding_yes
) | C:\PROGRA~1\PuTTY\plink -load test
```

---

The above will produce Windows CRLF line endings. Maybe your device needs *nix CR line endings. You can try the following PowerShell script (`script.ps1`):

```
Write-Host -NoNewline "root`n"
Start-Sleep 5
Write-Host -NoNewline "root`n"
Start-Sleep 5
# ...
```

And use it like:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File script.ps1 | C:\PROGRA~1\PuTTY\plink -load test
```